# Got an error while running first-network example, fabric version 1.2

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Env related : 
Mac OS High Sierra(version 10.13.6) 
Docker version 18.06.1-ce
fabric version 1.2.0 (installed by this command :

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh |bash -s 1.2.0)
```

You will see that there is an err after calling

```
./byfn.sh up
```

Log follows:

```
2018-09-04 02:37:21.047 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2018-09-04 02:37:21.047 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
Error: could not assemble transaction, err Proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg failed to execute transaction fc42719a6fc35ab6fbd661c80735003b55bf9d3a0d451875fbdc949dc40d05e6: error starting container: error starting container: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Chaincode instantiation on peer0.org2 on channel 'mychannel' failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========
ERROR !!!! Test failed
```

before that, when I called `./byfn.sh generate`, also got some warnings which is not compatable as the tutorial https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/build_network.html:

```
/Users/isme/Desktop/hpfbric/fabric-samples/first-network/../bin/configtxgen
##########################################################
#########  Generating Orderer Genesis block ##############
##########################################################
+ configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
2018-09-04 10:23:17.293 CST [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> WARN 001 Omitting the channel ID for configtxgen is deprecated.  Explicitly passing the channel ID will be required in the future, defaulting to 'testchainid'.
2018-09-04 10:23:17.293 CST [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> INFO 002 Loading configuration
2018-09-04 10:23:17.298 CST [common/tools/configtxgen/encoder] NewChannelGroup -> WARN 003 Default policy emission is deprecated, please include policy specificiations for the channel group in configtx.yaml
2018-09-04 10:23:17.298 CST [common/tools/configtxgen/encoder] NewOrdererGroup -> WARN 004 Default policy emission is deprecated, please include policy specificiations for the orderer group in configtx.yaml
2018-09-04 10:23:17.298 CST [common/tools/configtxgen/encoder] NewOrdererOrgGroup -> WARN 005 Default policy emission is deprecated, please include policy specificiations for the orderer org group OrdererOrg in configtx.yaml
2018-09-04 10:23:17.298 CST [msp] getMspConfig -> INFO 006 Loading NodeOUs
2018-09-04 10:23:17.298 CST [common/tools/configtxgen/encoder] NewOrdererOrgGroup -> WARN 007 Default policy emission is deprecated, please include policy specificiations for the orderer org group Org1MSP in configtx.yaml
2018-09-04 10:23:17.299 CST [msp] getMspConfig -> INFO 008 Loading NodeOUs
2018-09-04 10:23:17.299 CST [common/tools/configtxgen/encoder] NewOrdererOrgGroup -> WARN 009 Default policy emission is deprecated, please include policy specificiations for the orderer org group Org2MSP in configtx.yaml
2018-09-04 10:23:17.299 CST [common/tools/configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 00a Generating genesis block
2018-09-04 10:23:17.300 CST [common/tools/configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 00b Writing genesis block
+ res=0
+ set +x

#################################################################
### Generating channel configuration transaction 'channel.tx' ###
#################################################################
+ configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID mychannel
2018-09-04 10:23:17.325 CST [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2018-09-04 10:23:17.330 CST [common/tools/configtxgen] doOutputChannelCreateTx -> INFO 002 Generating new channel configtx
2018-09-04 10:23:17.330 CST [common/tools/configtxgen/encoder] NewApplicationGroup -> WARN 003 Default policy emission is deprecated, please include policy specificiations for the application group in configtx.yaml
2018-09-04 10:23:17.330 CST [msp] getMspConfig -> INFO 004 Loading NodeOUs
2018-09-04 10:23:17.330 CST [common/tools/configtxgen/encoder] NewApplicationOrgGroup -> WARN 005 Default policy emission is deprecated, please include policy specificiations for the application org group Org1MSP in configtx.yaml
2018-09-04 10:23:17.330 CST [msp] getMspConfig -> INFO 006 Loading NodeOUs
2018-09-04 10:23:17.331 CST [common/tools/configtxgen/encoder] NewApplicationOrgGroup -> WARN 007 Default policy emission is deprecated, please include policy specificiations for the application org group Org2MSP in configtx.yaml
2018-09-04 10:23:17.331 CST [common/tools/configtxgen] doOutputChannelCreateTx -> INFO 008 Writing new channel tx
+ res=0
+ set +x
```

Comment: Though those warnings and errs are generated at the first time I ran the scripts, after calling `./byfn.sh down` `./byfn.sh up` by sequence, I got the same results showed in the tutorial(Strange). Still confusing.